# grafana - Get a non time based output

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I would like to have a possibility in grafana to display data in a certain way.

Imagine we look at Formula one races. Every race has drivers, finishing the race in different times. The average time of finishing that race can be calculated. Every race has a name like "5. Circuit de Pedralbes" or "6. Fuji Speedway".

I want a graph where the names of the courses are on the X axis and the average times on the courses are on Y. The data is present in influx DB.

I can get the average from influx, that's easy. Does someone has a hint for in how to achieve this in grafana?

[image: Formula One Example]

Comment: Sounds like what bar chart does.

Comment: @markalex Bar Graph supports the individual x-Axis, ( time or String Value ), which is awesome, so the principle is known to grafana =)! this makes me optimistic!
What I'm still looking for is a graph with an actual line. Suppose I not only want to look at Formula 1, but also want to look at LE MANS, NESCAR, MOTOGP, MOTO2 , ..., to much bars would slightly confuse the spectator.